# What is the correct of saying between you and I?

Tags: grammaticality

I was taught that it is correct to say "between you and I," instead of "between you and me." Which is correct?

I forgot to mention that my father said if you left out the other person. the correct word will be "I" not "me'.  A person doesn't said "me" went to the store. A person would say "I" went to the store.